# Why doesn't XCode realise that I've synthesised my property?

Tags: cocoa-touch, properties, warnings, xcode4

In my interface, I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol AddCategoryDelegate;

@interface AddCategoryViewController : UIViewController {
    id <AddCategoryDelegate> _delegate; 
}

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) id <AddCategoryDelegate> delegate;    
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;    
- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender;

@end



@protocol AddCategoryDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addCategoryViewController:(AddCategoryViewController *)addCategoryViewController didAddCategory:category;

@end
```

And in my implementation, I have:

```
#import "AddCategoryViewController.h"

@implementation AddCategoryViewController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize textField;
@synthesize textLabel;

// methods

@end
```

But I keep getting the following warnings from XCode:

> Property 'textLabel' requires the
>   method 'setTextLabel:' to be defined -
>   use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a
>   method implementation.
>
> Property 'textLabel' requires the
>   method '-textLabel' to be defined -
>   use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a
>   method implementation.

Is this an XCode 4 bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worth noting: copying the above code doesn't result in the warning on my installation. Can you make sure there isn't a typo in the real code?

Otherwise, you could try removing the `IBOutlet` keyword from the variable declaration, and only keep it on the property declaration. That might be confusing things...

Comment: Having 2 IBOutlets seems like it could certainly be a problem; because I'd think IB would see both, and you wouldn't be able to tell which is which. Also, there's no need to have the iVar declared at all; @synthesize will do that automatically.

Comment: Thanks - I've removed the Ivars but the error messages are still the same. I've edited my question above so it is a copy-and-paste of the actual code, in case there are typos I've missed.

Comment: OK... a bit of googling turned up someone with a similar problem. I selected 'clean' from the product menu and that seems to have fixed it! Now, if someone would be kind enough to tell me what 'clean' is, and what I just did ... :)

Comment: You completely removed all the intermediate build information and forced Xcode to rebuild everything from scratch. Clearly there was some issue it wasn't detecting, so cleaning the target and rebuilding it corrected the situation.

Comment: FYI: same problem here and running clean did not fix. In fact, as soon as I hit clean, all the warnings went away EXCEPT that one... then as it analyzed my code (~0.25 seconds) another warning came up too. Closing and reopening the project worked for me.